# Normalize output without Softmax

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

Training with a `softmax` output layer for my generative neural network gives better results than with `relu` overall but `relu` gives me the sparsity I need (zeros in pixels).
`Softmax` also helps get a normalised output (i.e. sum =1.).

I want to do:

```
outputs = Dense(200, activation='softmax', activity_regularizer=l1(1e-5))(x)
outputs = Activation('relu')(outputs) # to get real zeros
outputs = Activation('softmax')(outputs) # still real zeros, normalized output
```

But by applying successive softmax I will get extreme outputs. Is there a layer I can use instead which just normalizes the output to 1 (output_i/sum(output)) instead of softmax ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add two softmax. Just the last one is fine:

```
outputs = Dense(200, activation='relu', activity_regularizer=l1(1e-5))(x)
outputs = Activation('softmax')(outputs) # still real zeros, normalized
```

Yet, if you have more intermediate layers and you want them to behave more moderately, you could use a "tanh" instead of softmax.

Often the problem with relu models is not exactly "they don't sum 1", but simply "their values are way to high, gradients can't behave well".

```python
#this combines a max output of 1 (but doesn't care about the sum)
#yet keeping the sparsity:
outputs = Dense(200, activation='tanh')(x)
outputs = Activation('relu')(outputs) # to get real zeros

outputs = Dense(200, activation='relu')(outputs)

#this should only be used at the final layer
#and only if you really have a classification model with only one correct class
outputs = Activation('softmax')(outputs) # still real zeros, normalized output
```

Softmax tends to favor only one of the results. If you don't want to change how results compare one to another and yet you want to make `sum=1`, you can go for @nuric's answer.

Comment: I need to impose a normalization of my output, with sum exactly = 1. Your suggestion is a very good one to improve on relu with tanh. But not the problem I'm trying to solve. My model is not classification, but I need a normalized output. I could try without softmax but instead unit norm like @nuric suggested

Comment: I see :) --- Even so, the only layer that actually needs a softmax is the last one. So you need to call "softmax" only once, and your results will not be so extreme.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own layer to convert the outputs to unit norm (ie normalise in your case) without applying a softmax. You can achieve by converting the output to a unit vector. Something along the lines of:

```
def unitnorm(x):
  return x / (K.epsilon() + K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(x), keepdims=True)))
# Wrap Lambda layer
outputs = Lambda(unitnorm, name='unitnorm')(outputs)
```

The code is from [unit norm constraint](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/14ff5175181e680d75b8d4ad6fe0d7d4dd35beff/keras/constraints.py#L91) which does the same for kernels and bias in layers. You can try without epsilon to be more precise but could be less stable when you have a lot of zeros.